# Ensure user X doesn't query user Y's data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Lets say I have an `Organisation` which has many `Student`'s. There exists a login for each `Organisation` which shows a list of related `Student`'s.

When viewing the list of `Student`'s I can edit those by clicking on one of them. This takes me to a page lets say `/students/edit/<id>`.

A query for the view of this page could get the students from my service layer:

```
public class StudentService : IStudentService {

     private readonly IRepository _repository; // injected in constructor

     public Student GetStudent(int id) {
          return _repository.Get<Student>(x => x.Id = id);
     }
}
```

My questions are:

1. How do I ensure that organisation X does not query organisation Y's data (e.g. by using a different id in the querystring which does not belong to this organisation logged in)?
2. Should the service layer be adding the extra joins (`&& x.OrganisationId == <organisation id>`) to make sure that the
   currently logged in `Organisation` is the only one which data is
   queried from? How do I get the current user from the service layer?
3. Should I add an extra parameter to the `GetStudent(int id, int organisationId)` and let the controller set it? This just seem to bloat my services.

I hope I have explained this well, please let me know if I am confusing my self ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making your service aware of the current authenticated user.  That will allow you to include a limiting `Where` clause similar to the below in each query to prevent users from seeing other organisations students

```
 private Student GetStudent(int id) {
      return _repository
        .Get<Student>(x => x.Id = id)
        .Where(s => s.OrganisationId == _currentUser.OrganisationId)
        .FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

Comment: How can I make my service aware of the currently logged in user? How do I get the ASP.NET Identity user in here? :-)

Comment: I wish not to create a dependency on the UI from the service layer.

Comment: Assuming that you have some form of user ID on your `Identity` object that maps onto the DB field then you could expose the current users' ID through your IoC framework.  Alternatively you could create a custom Identity object and expose that, which is more work but more useful in the future.

Comment: is it possible for you to come up with a simple example on how to expose an identity object in my service?

Comment: Are you using a DI/IoC container?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ninject but I assume you can push an instance into the container. Use that mechanism to push an instance of your custom identity class into Ninject from somewhere that *can* be tied to the ASP.NET identity system, then have that injected into your service constructor

Answer (score 1):

I developed a web app last year that had a similar scenario. What I did was to create a method called GetFilteredQueryable in each of my Repositories which takes as its parameter the currently logged in user's username (we prefer using email address, but anything works really). For instance, when searching student records, I would do the following:

```
IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentsHavingSubject(string subjectCode, string curUser)
{
    var Students = this.GetFilteredQueryable<Student>(CurUser);
    Students = Students.Where(x => x.subjects.Any(y=>y.SubjectCode == subjectCode));
    return Students.AsEnumerable();
}

IQueryable<Student> GetFilteredQueryable(curUser)
{
    //you could do any other checks in here too, like user level, permissions, etc.
    return DB.Students.Where(x => x.Organization.Users.Any(y=>y.UserName == curUser));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend simply adding a parameter for the organisationId. When writing methods always imagine writing tests for your method. If it'll be awkward to write the test you should probably refactor your method.

Passing an organisationId parameter is very straightforward and clean.